# No module named 'MBI' in CADRE plug-in

Tags: openmdao

When I try to run CADRE plug-in it fails when trying to import 'MBI' module in 'CADRE.power' discipline:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Laurynas\CADRE\src\mppt.py", line 9, in <module>
    from CADRE.power import Power_SolarPower, Power_CellVoltage
  File "C:\Users\Laurynas\CADRE\src\CADRE\power.py", line 10, in <module>
    from MBI import MBI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MBI'
```

Is this some kind of legacy python or OpenMDAO module? I was not able to find it in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, MBI is a separate package, but you can find it here:

https://github.com/OpenMDAO/MBI